# Are decision trees sensitive to translations in feature space?

Tags: cart, feature-engineering

Based on my understanding, a translation ( x' = x + a ) for any feature, x, by an amount, a, should not effect the results of a decision tree. I wanted to ensure this was true in all cases independent of:

1. Split criterion
2. Outliers
3. Classification vs Regression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I understand you mean Gini impurity/entropy. To see independence of splitting criterion, note that Gini impurity and entropy measures are translation invariant.
2. I don't understand what this has to do with outliers.
3. Same as impurity/entropy, variance is invariant under translations, so adding something to a feature doesn't affect tree construction for regression.

Comment: 1) There are many other split criterion like Hellinger distance. 2) Just trying to come up with possibilities 3) As I thought. LONG STORY SHORT: No, Decision trees are not sensitive to translations.

Comment: Commonly used exhaustive-search trees are invariant to monotonic transformations of the features or explanatory variables (e.g., CART, C4.5, etc.). The reason is that all criteria just evaluate binary (typically) splits in these variables. However, there are also tree induction methods that try to exploit linear associations (e.g., the inference-based CTree algorithm with default settings). These are invariant against linear transformations but not against nonlinear transfromations. Typically, those algorithms can be tweaked though to be invariant if that is desired.