# Are decision trees sensitive to log translations in feature space?

Tags: machine-learning, cart, rpart, gini

This question was partially answered on [Are decision trees sensitive to translations in feature space?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/319621/are-decision-trees-sensitive-to-translations-in-feature-space), but no references were provided for "Gini impurity and entropy measures are translation invariant". 
I couldn't find material relating to this topic, so does anyone know either:
a) Why Gini is translation invariant, or
b) Why the results of a decision tree would be otherwise insensitive to translations (e.g. log) in the feature space?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what algorithm is being used to build the tree. CART trees are invariant to scale changes so a log transform should not change the resulting tree. However, the values of the split rules will be changed to the log scale.

The reason for this is because the splitting process sorts each feature (numeric) and then checks midpoints between successive observations for impurity improvement based on splits at the interval point. The maximum across observations and features is chosen for that node and the process continues. This means that if you rescale any feature(s) as long as the relative ordering of feature values is maintained-which a log transform will maintain-the tree will be the same but the split values will be log-transformed.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I was referring to trees grown via CART. Do you have any information as to why CART trees are invariant to scale/ non-linear transformations?

Comment: @DataAnalyticsAnalyst will add a description of why CART trees are invariant to scale changes to my answer.

Comment: Wouldn’t the only issues here be with in machine precision? That is, taking the log of a very small number could aid in sorting; I’m thinking similar to how we always take the log of the likelihood in maximum likelihood estimation.

Comment: @Mark White -> Not sure how taking a log transform would aid in sorting. Assuming all observations are positive the log transform preserves the ordering. Most sorting algorithms use a binary comparison with a partial ordering so the numeric magnitudes are (usually) not relevant. What did you have in mind?

Comment: This probably won't be very useful in 99.999% of applications, but imagine we have predictors that are incredibly small, e.g., 6e-40, or something. Calculations might be hard to do well at that precision, so taking the log would help with precision. For instance, the difference between 7e-40 and 6e-40 is so small, but the difference between the log(7e-40) and log(6e-40) is 0.1541507, which is easier for a computer to handle. Again, this is more of a theoretical comment on my part than something OP should worry about, but I was wondering when the log might make a difference.

Comment: Note that there are also tree induction algorithms that do not only rely on tests of binary splits at midpoints but also on tests of linear associations (e.g., the CTree algoirthm with default settings). Consequently, such algorithms are invariant against linear transformations but not nonlinear transformations (like logs).

Comment: @AchimZeileis yes very good point about split types that are non-necessarily univariate. Hopefully the first sentence of my answer "
It depends on what algorithm is being used to build the tree." caveats this enough that readers are not mislead.

Comment: It's not just splits in linear combinations. CTree selects in each leaf a variable for splitting by running an association test of y and each x_j before selecting the split point in the best x_j*. The default test in the R package `partykit` (or the older `party`) is for linear associations between y and x_j and hence not invariant to nonlinear transformations. Of course, the default can be changed, e.g., to a test of monotonic rank correlations our maximally selected statistics. But it's a common misconception among our users that transformations do not matter at all.